# ACF Meta_Query and Get_posts is not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, post-type

I am trying to query custom post type but I keep getting no result. Is my meta_query the culprit? What is wrong with this code?
I am trying to spot the issues but i cannot find anything.

```
$catname = 'travel';
$priority ='high';
$status = 'incomplete';
$args = array(     
          'post_type'       =>   'my_gallery_post',
          'orderby'         =>   'id',
            //'fields'      => 'ids',
          'sort_order'      =>   'asc',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'  =>    1,
           'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'category_it_belongs',
                        'value'   => $catname,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'levelof_priority',
                        'value'   => $priority,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'progress',
                        'value'   => $status,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                )
            
        
      );
$mypost = get_posts($args);

print_r($mypost);
```

Output

```
Array()
```

Comment: Replace `'sort_order'      =>   'asc' ` to `'order'      =>   'asc'`

Comment: @ParthaviPatel nope. didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using array for 'levelof_priority'.
The field type for 'levelof_priority' is radio button whereas the other 2 are text field.

Below are my final code that's working

```
$catname = 'travel';
$priority ='high';
$status = 'incomplete';
$args = array(     
          'post_type'       =>   'my_gallery_post',
          'orderby'         =>   'id',
            //'fields'      => 'ids',
          'sort_order'      =>   'asc',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'  =>    1,
           'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'category_it_belongs',
                        'value'   => $catname,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'levelof_priority',
                        'value'   => array($priority),
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'progress',
                        'value'   => $status,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                )
            
        
      );
$mypost = get_posts($args);

print_r($mypost);
```